# Conditional Probability regarding union

Tags: conditional-probability

How would I solve this problem if the conditional probability for $\mathsf P(B \mid A)$ is not listed? Also, in Bayes' Theorem only intersection is listed, not Union. How would I find Union?

$\mathsf P( A \cup B)$ if it is given that $\mathsf P(A)=1/3$ and $\mathsf P(B \mid A^c)=1/4$

Answer (score 0):

Use the following equalities:
$\begin{cases}\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\cup B) &= \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B) - \mathsf P(A\cap B) & \tag{Inclusion/Exclusion}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(A\cap B) &= \mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A^c\cap B) & \tag{Complementation}
\\ \mathsf P(A) & = 1 - \mathsf P(A^c)
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(B\mid A^c) &= \frac{\mathsf P(A^c\cap B)}{\mathsf P(A^c)} & \tag{Bayes' Rule}
\end{align}\end{cases}$